# What is the one word expression for 'wayside grass'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I knew a word that meant wayside grass in English; but now I can not remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you thinking of [verge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/verge)?

Comment: This answers verges on the correct.

Comment: grrr... "answer", I meant...

Answer (score 1):

If not the verge, then perhaps the median, which is the (usually grassy) strip in the middle of a divided road.

Answer (score -1):

You probably weren't thinking of **way-waste**; but I like it so much I have to suggest it.